# Find method signature for selectors in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Where can I find the method signature for callback methods in built-in classes like UIGestureRecognizer or UIMenuItem etc?

e.g., documentation states for **UIMenuItem**:

> **initWithTitle:action:**
>   Creates and returns a menu-item object initialized with the given title and action.
>
> -(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title action:(SEL)action*
>
> **Parameters**
>   *title*
>   The title of the menu item.
>   *action*
>   A selector identifying the method of the responder object to invoke for handling the command represented by the menu item.
>   **Return Value**
>   An initialized UIMenuItem object, or nil if there was a problem creating the object.

How do I know what parameter 'action' may receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for the [Target-Action Mechanism in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44). Specifically it mentions the following:

> In contrast with the Application Kit, where an action method may have only one or perhaps two valid signatures, the UIKit framework allows three different forms of action selector:
>
> - `- (void)action`
> - `- (void)action:(id)sender`
> - `- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Answer (score 1):

'action' is a convention in Cocoa Touch/UIKit : [Target-Action in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44)

Actions can have any of the following three signatures in UIKit:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: UIKit [differs somewhat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44) in convention.

Comment: That's for Cocoa; in Cocoa Touch, the action method can take any of three forms, all of which are documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44